# Typing dataclass that can only take enum values

Tags: python, enums, python-typing, typing

I have a dataclass that can take values that are part of an enum.

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = "valueA"
    B = "valueB"

@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    value: MyEnum
```

When creating my dataclass, the types don't match as it is considering `str` != `MyEnum.A`.

```py
param = MyDataclass(value="valueA")
```

Any suggestion on how should `MyDataclass` be typed instead?

EDIT: The dataclass is being initialized with the string values I receive from another API

Comment: Try `value=MyEnum.A`

Comment: The problem is that my dataclass is initialized as part of an external API, so I can't really change the way I pass the value to the dataclass unless I make conditional for all possible values

Comment: Why don't you use constructor `MyEnum("valueA")`?

Comment: What error do you get with `MyDataclass(value="valueA")`? Dataclasses don't do any type-checking; the type hint only serves to mark the name as something `dataclass` should pay attention to.

Comment: Dataclasses won't do any kind of automatic type conversion, either. If a string gets passed to `__init__`, that's what will be assigned to the attribute. If you want to convert the string to a `MyEnum` value, the simplest solution would be to do that in `__post_init__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class is *typed* correctly if you really want `MyDataclass().value` to be a `MyEnum` value. The problem is that *you*, as the person instantiating `MyDataclass`, are responsible for actually passing a value of type `MyEnum` to `__init__`.

If your use case requires a string to be passed, you'll have to handle the conversion yourself in `__post_init__`, which does mean altering the class definition slightly.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field


@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    value: MyEnum = field(init=False)
    value_str: InitVar[str]

    def __post_init__(self, value_str):
        self.value = MyEnum(value_str)
```

Automatic conversion will require a different library, for example Pydantic or (I believe) `attrs`; it's not a feature that `dataclasses` supplies.

The amount of static type protection this gives you is limited, because you are stating that *any* string can be passed as an argument to `__init__`/`__post_init__`, but really only the ones that are valid arguments to `MyEnum` are valid. This isn't really something that can be expressed using the `typing` module, as `Enum` itself isn't designed with static type checking in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

class MyEnum(Enum):
A: str = "INLIVE"
B: str = "PRELIVE"

```
@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    value: Enum = field(default=MyEnum)

print(asdict(MyDataclass(value=MyEnum.B)))
```